# Apply Theme to everything

Tags: theme

I bought and applied a new RWD theme called Ultimo to my 1.6.1 Magento store.

I followed the instructions and went into system > configuration and changed the package name to 'Ultimo' and the Theme setting to default.

After I did this I made sure I flushed the cache,cookies etc in Magento + Browser.

So when I go onto the customer side it still looks exactly as it did before the theme.

I have to manually go into each category or page and select Custom Design > Ultimo for any changes to appear.

This has ended up taking me a very long time, manually selecting the theme each time.

What are my options here?

Comment: Do you have any thing saved under System >> Design?

Comment: Yes there is one thing there.

Comment: Remove it please

Comment: I have removed it and all is well, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you have one of three other theme overrides in place:

1. A theme is set in the theme scheduler in System > Design - if so, remove it.
2. You have a theme set on the store view and not the global view in the system configuration panel. Go to System > Configuration and check the values from the dropdown in the top left that allow you to choose website or store view.
3. If either of the above prove unhelpful you *may* have a theme being set programmatically, perhaps from your last theme install. I would [disable all local Magento modules](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-disable-all-local-modules-at-once/) and [follow the standard debugging process](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/).

Comment: It was step 1.! 
I've taken over from somebody else and I don't know what he's done with the website so far.
Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad to hear it!